# when trying to store a value in array its not being added properly

Tags: javascript, dom, web-storage

So right now im in the stages of making a todo list.

The stage im at is to when i click the button it adds the text i typed in the box, but then its suppose to also with a for loop store it locally.

The value entered is supposed to be stored here:
https://gyazo.com/cb156bc01383343ddaeb7b41d2e622a9
In the console u can see that the array is just empty and not showing the values like its suppose to.

This is the code section that is handling this:

```
var lagring = document.getElementsByClassName("produkter");

    var tempArr = [];

    //loopar listan
    for(i=0; i<lagring.length; i++) {
        tempArr.push(lagring[i].innerHTML);
    }

    console.log(tempArr);
```

The full code will be linked below.

So why isnt the value im entering into the box, when it gets added to the list(that works) but storing it in the array doesnt.

full code:

HTML:

```js
    //Kod skapad av Emil Palm
    "use strict";
    
    //Variabler
    
    var addProdukt = document.getElementById("newtodo");
    var addProduktButton = document.getElementById("newtodobutton");
    var errorMessage = document.getElementById("message");
    var toDoList = document.getElementById("todolist");
    var i;
    
    
    // Händelsehanterare
    
    addProdukt.addEventListener("keyup", checkInput, false);
    addProduktButton.addEventListener("click", addProdukt1, false);
    window.onload = init;
    
    
    
    //Initieringsfunktion
    
    function init() {
        console.log("Initierar...");
    
            //Läs in Produktlista
    
            loadProdukter();
    
    // Inaktivera knappen
    
        addProduktButton.disabled = true;
    
    }
    
    
    
    
    // Kontrollera input
    
    function checkInput() {
        console.log("Kontrollerar input...");
    
        var input = addProdukt.value;
    
        // Kontrollera längd
    
        if(input.length > 4) {
    
            errorMessage.innerHTML = "";
            addProduktButton.disabled = false;
    
        } else {
            errorMessage.innerHTML = "Måste innehålla minst 5 tecken";
            addProduktButton.disabled = true;
        }
    }
    
    
    // Lägg till produkt
    
    function addProdukt1() {
        console.log("Lägger till Produkt...");
    // Skapar nytt element
        var input = addProdukt.value;
    
        var newEl = document.createElement("article");
        var newTextNode = document.createTextNode(input);
        newEl.appendChild(newTextNode);
        newEl.className = "Produkter";
    // lägger till i lista
        toDoList.appendChild(newEl);
    
        addProdukt.value = "";
        addProduktButton.disabled = true;
    
    
    
    //Anropar lagring
    
    saveProdukter();
    
    }
    
    
    
    // Spara produkter
    
    function saveProdukter() {
        console.log("Lagrar produktlista...");
    
        var lagring = document.getElementsByClassName("produkter");
    
        var tempArr = [];
    
        //loopar listan
        for(i=0; i<lagring.length; i++) {
            tempArr.push(lagring[i].innerHTML);
        }
    
        console.log(tempArr);
    }
    
    
    //Läs in produkter
    
    function loadProdukter() {
        console.log("Läser in Produktlista")
    }
```

```html
<body>
        <header id="mainheader">
            <div class="contain">
                <h1 id="logo">DT084G</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /.contain -->
        </header>
    
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Laboration 3 - DOM och events</h2>
    
            <h3>Lägg till ny sak att göra</h3>
    
            <section id="new">
                <label for="newtodo">Att göra:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="newtodo">&nbsp;
                <button class="btn" id="newtodobutton">Lägg till</button><br>
                <span id="message"></span>
            </section>
    
            <h3>Saker att göra</h3>
            <section id="todolist">
                
            </section>
    
            <button id="clearbutton" class="btn">Rensa</button>
    
            <footer>
                <p>Laborationsuppgift för kursen DT084G, Introduktion till programmering med JavaScript.</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    
    </body>
```

Comment: In the picture you can see the values being shown on the site to the left after clicking the button but the value between the [] is empty in the console

Comment: You aren't doing anything with `tempArr` you create it in your function but do nothing else with it. It will be gone at the end of that function call,

Comment: Yes its blank, and then i use the push command to enter values in it?

Comment: Right there: 'code'tempArr.push(lagring[i].innerHTML);'code'

Comment: Yes but after that you dont save the array anywhere. `tempArr` is temporary as it is created in that function therefore only exists there till the end of that function. Each call to that function is going to create a new `tempArr`

Comment: The thing is tho for my teacher showing the example made it exactly the same code, and in the console u can see the values inside the [], I know it wiped if i refresh atm but for him at this stage u can see it like this: [link]https://gyazo.com/1f1c458f8ff18fc6212dc165ce83c3ba for me its just blank between the []

Comment: I solved it, in the one where i add a class to the element I had a big "P" compared to other places